# Loading xml and binding to ListBox is very slow on Windows phone

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I read this xml file and bind it to listBox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<category name="category_alphabet" type="grid" icon="icon_alphabet" tabStyle="alphabetic"    tabStepSize="5">
<item>
    <id>dk1-1</id>
    <label>A</label>
    <file>a</file>
</item>
<item>
    <id>dk1-2</id>
    <label>B</label>
    <file>b</file>
</item>
.
.
.
```

and it has 29 items

i read that xml file with these codes and i call it after InitializeComponent() in page1.xaml constructor :

```
var loadedData = XDocument.Load("alphabet.xml").Descendants("item");

var alphabetItems = (from query in loadedData select new CategoryItem
{
    Id = (string)query.Element("id"),
    File = (string)query.Element("file"),
    Label = (string)query.Element("label")
}).ToList();

ListBoxAlphabet.ItemsSource = alphabetItems;
```

and this is xaml file :

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxAlphabet">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <controls:RoundButton Content="{Binding Label}"
                                      FontSize="30" Margin="1" 
                                      ButtonHeight="80" ButtonWidth="80"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                      Background="#FFD0D2D3" Foreground="White"
                                      PressedBrush="#F9A11D" 
                                      BorderBrush="{Binding Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                      />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

the speed of reading xml file is ok but the speed of binding to listbox is very slow ! it takes 7-8 seconds to load and it is not normal . 
what should i do ?

Comment: What happens if you just bind to a normal ListBox without the WrapPanel template?

Comment: Does it speed up if you don't use the render transform?

Comment: Can you try getting rid of the ToList() ?

Comment: Hi , i found a way to resolve the problem , if i remove this line of code from xaml everything will be ok ! 
BorderBrush="{Binding Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

but what is wrong with that BorderBrush...  ?